# Add Custom Endpoints for Wordpress API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, endpoint

I want to build some custom API endpoints for Wordpress using its API methods and Regarding to this docs

[https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/](http://ByConsole%20Woocommerce%20Order%20Delivery%20Time%20management)

I found that they explained everything but I don't know where to start where I should setup my files or where to set them in.

Need to know where to set the code in which files or will generate new .php and include it ???

Also if any can reference any tutorials to make build custom endpoints for this plugin in Wordpress

> ByConsole Woocommerce Order Delivery Time management

Thanks in advance, regarding duplication its not duplicated here am asking about where to set up my code not how to use it.

Comment: you can add all examples provided in the link you referred to in the `functions.php` file. Just to see what happens and so on. Ideally you either build your own file structure or plugin later on.  But for now you can work in the theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: More examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwordpress%5D+rest-api+custom+endpoints

Answer (score 5):

Easy and simplest way to extend REST API in WP.

Create 2 files in below location

```
 1. wp-content/themes/yourTheme/API/wp-rest-api-base.php
    
 2. wp-content/themes/yourTheme/API/wp-rest-api-func.php
```

And then include both files in your current theme's `functions.php`

```
require get_parent_theme_file_path('API/wp-rest-api-base.php');
require get_parent_theme_file_path('API/wp-rest-api-func.php');
```

Now you have 2 custom endpoints that can be access via

> with `POST` Method : `http://website.com/wp-json/api/v1/promotions`
>
> with `GET` Method : `http://website.com/wp-json/api/v1/location_based_notify`

`ApiDefaultController` construct require method name to be called when the request is made with specific end point.

Note: Your method should not return JSON data because it will be done by WP REST structure, all you need is to return array of data and then your request will return `JSON` response.

**wp-rest-api-base.php**

```
<?php

class ApiBaseController extends WP_REST_Controller {
    //The namespace and version for the REST SERVER
    var $my_namespace = 'api/v';
    var $my_version = '1';
    public function register_routes() {
        $namespace = $this->my_namespace.$this->my_version;
        
        register_rest_route($namespace, '/promotions', array(
                array(
                    'methods'  => 'POST',
                    'callback' => array(new ApiDefaultController('cms_promotions'), 'init'),
                )
            )
        );

        register_rest_route($namespace, '/location_based_notify', array(
                array(
                    'methods'  => 'GET',
                    'callback' => array(new ApiDefaultController('location_based_notify'), 'init'),
                )
            )
        );
    }
    // Register our REST Server
    public function hook_rest_server() {
        add_action('rest_api_init', array($this, 'register_routes'));
        //add_action('rest_api_init', 'my_customize_rest_cors', 15);
    }
    public function my_customize_rest_cors() {
        remove_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers');
        remove_filter('rest_post_dispatch', 'rest_send_allow_header');
    }
}

$ApiBaseController = new ApiBaseController();
$ApiBaseController->hook_rest_server();
```

**wp-rest-api-func.php**

```
<?php

class ApiDefaultController extends ApiBaseController
{
    public $method;
    public $response;

    public function __construct($method)
    {
        $this->method = $method;
        $this->response = array(
            'Status' => false,
            'StatusCode' => 0,
            'StatusMessage' => 'Default'
        );
    }

    private $status_codes = array(
        'success' => true,
        'failure' => 0,
        'missing_param' => 150,
    );

    public function init(WP_REST_Request $request)
    {
        try {
            if (!method_exists($this, $this->method)) {
                throw new Exception('No method exists', 500);
            }
            $data = $this->{$this->method}($request);
            $this->response['Status'] = $this->status_codes['success'];
            $this->response['StatusCode'] = 1000;
            $this->response['StatusMessage'] = 'success';
            $this->response['Data'] = $data;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->response['Status'] = false;
            $this->response['StatusCode'] = $e->getCode();
            $this->response['StatusMessage'] = $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->response;
    }

    public function cms_promotions($request)
    {
        $data = array();

        return $data;
    }

    public function location_based_notify($request)
    {
        $data = array();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer will try it and feedback